# Can we execute partitioner multiple times in the same run?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

We want to process three million records on a single batch run. At the end, the batch will create a file with three million records.

So, we thought to create a partitioner which will query the database for 100k records and process it. We want the partitioner has to be called again to read next set of 100k records.

How can we implement this to execute partitioner with different ranges?

Answer (score 0):

> How can we implement this to execute partitioner with different ranges?

You can take a look at the [ColumnRangePartitioner](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/common/ColumnRangePartitioner.java) from the samples.